# Using wildcards in LDAP query to match trustParent property

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm using code like below to build a tree of domains using LDAP query.

```
        DirectorySearcher configSearch = new DirectorySearcher(
            context.AuthContext.ConfigurationDirectoryEntry)

        configSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(netbiosname=*)(trustParent=CN={0},CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,{1}))",
                    parentFolder.Name.Split('.').First(), parentFolder.GetNcName());

        // Configure search properties to return
        configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dnsroot");
        configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ncname");
        configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("netbiosname");
        configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("trustParent");
        SearchResultCollection forestPartitionList = configSearch.FindAll();

        // Loop through each returned domain in the result collection
        foreach (SearchResult domainPartition in forestPartitionList)
        {
            // Use domain information
        }
```

Such an LDAP filter works properly:

```
(trustParent=CN=**NETBIOSNAME**,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com)
```

However, a version with wildcards doesn't work (returns empty results):

```
(trustParent=*,DC=domain,DC=com)
```

I'm using the query in a stateless web app, so I have only parent domain name as input and I want to avoid additional LDAP query to get a NetBIOS name or DistinguishedName (of a remote AD domain, which may belong to another sub-network).

Any hints to filter the search result on trustParent property using wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the syntax of the trustParent attribute is a DistinguishedName, then it's not possible to do wildcard match, as there is no standard for matching substrings on a DistinguishedName in LDAP.